# How do I restrict my local.xml from being seen by outsiders,

Tags: magento

How do I restrict my `local.xml` from being seen by outsiders, as in Magento's `app/etc/local.xml` which has all the database access information.

Please specify the file paths where i need to make changes,
thanks

Answer (score 4):

http://www.domainname.com/app/etc/local.xml is forbidden by .htaccess of magento with default setting. Please check your .htaccess.
If you don't have htaccess file you can get `.htaccess.sample` , just rename it by `.htaccess`

Comment: Magento uses more than the Magento Root .htaccess file to control access to subdirectories. List contents of `app/`, `app/etc/` using a means that shows hidden files on a properly installed Magento instance and you will see the directory level .htaccess files set in place to explicitly deny access to the directory contents.

Answer (score 2):

All the request in magento or any mvc structure website goes to index.php page. If you see  .htaccess file  of magento carefully, you can get

> RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Allow access for images,skins and Javascript

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

So by default .xml files are forbidden (403)

Comment: Code is there but anyhow anyone can access my local.xml file.

## rewrite everything else to index.php


    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]




RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (bingbot|Baiduspider-image|msnbot|msnbot-media|Baiduspider|AhrefsBot|ProductAdsBot) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]



</IfModule>

Comment: I didn't get you. Exactly what you want to say ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running Apache, you need to find out how your chosen web server controls file access and translate the .htaccess files found in the stock Magento install to the control access method used.

If you're using Apache, you may need to turn on it's ability to read directory level .htaccess files. You then need to check and make sure the proper .htaccess files are installed in their directories.

For use under Apache Web Server, Magento extensively uses directory level .htaccess files to control access to its application folders, for example:

```
app/.htaccess
app/etc/.htaccess
```

should both exist and should contain

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

If they're missing, this is a sign that the developer designed the site on a WAMP stack and didn't understand how to set up FTP transfer to transfer hidden files. This also means that all the other .htaccess files are missing in critical areas like `media/.htaccess` which have even more necessary contents to shut off execution of php code out of potentially world writable directory trees (bad security):

```
Options All -Indexes

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

php_flag engine 0

</IfModule>

AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Basically, you need to download the Magento installer file and check its contents for all the missing `.htaccess` files that Magento puts in its various directories to control access.